# My ASP.NET Core Web Application doesn't open when I run it in an offline PC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I created my very first web application using **ASP.NET Core with .Net Core 3.1** and I published choosing the **File System** approach. This created a published folder and I found inside what I assume is the "web server" called *MyWebSite.exe*. After I click on the executable file I see a terminal window open saying that the web server is running and is listening for ports in localhost:5000 and localhost:5001. This is in my machine which is connected to the internet and I see my website no problem after I open a web browser and enter https://localhost:5001.

But, when I place this folder in a computer that is offline and run the MyWebSite.exe the terminal window doesn't open! Of course, I can hazard a guess as to why, but the hope is to be able to run my web app without online connectivity in some of my client's machines. Is there a way to configure my web application to start in "offline mode"? Or does this configuration need to happen in Windows?

Comment: There's no offline mode. Your application crashes, but you can't see the error message because the application terminates. Instead of double-clicking on the `exe`, open a console or terminal window, go to that folder and execute the application. When it crashes you'll see the error message. I'd guess there's no .NET Core runtime installed on that machine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see. I'm sure this is a pretty dumb question but how do I install .Net Core runtime? Will this machine need to install Visual Studio?

Comment: No, you won't need Visual Studio. How you install the runtime depends on your OS, Microsoft has plenty of documentation for the various OS's walking you through installation. It's a quick web search away.

Comment: @mason Thank you all. I'll go on and download .net core runtime on one of the offline machines and see what can be done. Cheers!